# ejecutar .bat alojado en server desde C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, batch, windows-server

Tengo un .bat alojando en un servidor windows server.
Nombre del servidor: ServerDb.
Direccion de .bat: D:\Carpeta1\Scripts\Launcher.bat

localmente yo puedo ejecutar asi un bat:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\iccmsdos\test\xload2.bat");
```

pero no se como ejecutar el .bat en el server desde el cliente.
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas? Si ejecutas un `.bat` en el servidor, el resultado se aplicará en el servidor y no en el cliente, ¿es eso lo que quieres o quieres que se ejecute el .bat en el cliente?

Comment: el .bat ejecuta un .exe que recolecta datos de una dB crea un .txt y posteriormente lanza otro .exe de un tercero que llama el .txt creado anteriormente para mandar esos datos del txt al sistema del tercero, sabes como ejecutarlo @KroneauxSchneider?

Comment: el resultado solo se debe de aplicar en el servidor, el cliente solo debe de mandar a ejecutarlo

Comment: El cliente debe ejecutar el .exe ¿desde donde? ¿aplicación aspx? ¿windows form? ¿por deterninar?

Comment: windows forms @RogerTorné

Comment: Es algo amplia tu pregunta, puede que necesites un servidor de aplicaciones, o puede que te sirva que sea el propio motor de base de datos el que ejecute el BAT.

Comment: Lo más práctico es que se ejecute desde la base de datos, si es que no tienes nada más. Si esto no fuera posible, deberás montar algún tipo de servicio que el cliente pueda alcanzar, por ejemplo un simple aspx en el IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui dejo como lo solucione:
Primer descargue PSTools donde viene el PSExec.exe que ayuda a ejecutar procesos remotos.

```html
using System.Diagnostics;
try
            {
                
                string server = "NameServer or IP";
                ProcessStartInfo startRecol = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startRecol.FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"PSExec.exe");
                startRecol.Arguments = @" -s -d \\" + server + @" -u na\UserName -p password -i D:\carpeta\LauncherPoll.bat";
                startRecol.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                startRecol.UseShellExecute = false;
                 Process p = Process.Start(startRecol);
                 p.WaitForExit();
                
                  MessageBox.Show("Ejecucion terminada con exito");
               
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
```

Tratare de emplicar el codigo que es poco pero me ayudo a solucionar mi problema presentado.
en la variable server asigno el nombre del servidor o la IP, despues inciailizamos processstartinfo en la propieda Filename cargamos desde la ruta donde inicia la aplicacion el PSExec.exe, yo decidi copir a la carpeta raiz el exe y la ruta la obtengo con Path.Combine, en la propiedad Arguments agrego el usuario y password con el que se ejecutar el proceso esto es muy importante debe de tener permisos de administrador el usuario, tambien pasamos la ruta del .bat y el nombre del server.
Con process.start() mandamos a ejecutar el proceso en el servidor y listo!!

Espero que a alguien mas le ayude.

Saludos.